# How do I connect an app (Angular 2 in Visual Studio Code) with a database in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, angular, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

I have done the Angular 2 Tutorial and the Tutorial "Building your first ASP.NET Core MVC app with Visual Studio" and now i want du connect my Angular App with the APS.NET, what i have to do?

Comment: This question is too broad for StackOverflow. Usually an Angular2 app doesn't connect to a database. You need a server that connects to a database and provides a (REST) API that executes database operations in the database and takes commands from an Angular2 application using HTTP requests.

Comment: Ok, i start a education and i have to build up an Contact form, so i build it up in Angular 2 and now i have to made it connectable to a Server and i now i do not know how to?! (could you answer in German mabye?)

Comment: I guess you better look for tutorials. This is the wrong channel for this kind of question. If you have a more concrete problem with some code you have written, then this is probably a good question for SO.

Comment: The Problem is that i have no idea where i have to search for ?

Comment: Questions about external resources like libraries, books, tutorials, ... are discouraged on SO. Try for example https://gitter.im/angular/angular or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/angular instead.

Comment: Shawn Wildermuth has a brilliant course on Pluralsight - Building a Web App with ASP.NET Core, MVC 6, EF Core, and Angular. This will introduce you to the fundamentals for all the server functionality to provide a Web API which will return data from a database using Entity Framework Core. The course also addresses how to call the Web API from Angular (1.5), sending requests and receiving responses with the data in return. Once you grasp the principals you can replicate the general principals using Angular 2.